# Numerical integration by the Romberg method using CUDA

Tags: cuda, numerical-integration

I tried searching for libraries on Google for numerical integration on CUDA but couldn't find any.

1) I want to ask, are there any libraries available to perform integration (of a function) on CUDA?

2) If I write my own code on CUDA, e.g. implementing Romberg Integration, how shall I proceed? Suppose I have function, say `f(x)`; do I need to calculate the integrals of this function for different intervals e.g. `0.0 - 0.1`, ..., `0.2 - 0.3`, ..., `1.3 - 2.3`? how do I calculate all of them in parallel?

In my mind, the strategy is that if I have to perform, e.g., `1000` integrations, I generate `1000` threads, each thread calculates trapzoids as well as the error estimates. But in case when I want to calculate trapzoids for one of the integration interval in parallel along with other integrals, I don't have any idea how to approach this programatically.

Comment: Well, do you know how CUDA (and GPGPU programmming in general) works (and not on the level of *"run a bunch of threads in parallel"*, but on the level of *"thread blocks"*, *"intra-block-synchronization"*, *"shared vs. global memory"*, ...)? If yes, then your task sounds reasonably easy to parallalize, like you said, start a bunch of threads, each intergrating a single interval (if you want the interval to sum afterwards, perform an additive reduction). If not, then start with a proper CUDA learning resource.

Comment: Yes, I understand the working of CUDA. I understand that I can start a thread block, where each thread can perform an integral over an interval on function f(x). But this way I parallalize integrals. But each integral itself is executed sequentially. Just the way any serial program on CPU might work. Isn't there any way where each integral can also be parallalized. e.g. I can calculate trapzoids in parallel for a given interval for X repetitions. While at the same time i can execute other integrals in parallel.

Comment: Are there any libraries available to perform integration?

Comment: Well, *Romberg* is hierarchical if I remember correctly, so the individual terms aren't parallelizable that well, I think. But you could just use something sufficiently simple like a piecewise *Trapzoid* or even *Rectangle* and use thousands of small intervals, doing a reduction afterwards. What is it really you want to parallelize, do you want to compute the integral of a single function in parallel, of many unrelated intervals of a single function, or multiple integrals of different functions? Of course a single thread works sequentially, that's why you have thousands to millions of them.

Comment: I have two step task.
Step 1: Creating a integral function (Romberg e.g.) that can integrate a function that I pass to it.

Step 2: Executing this integral function in parallel for 1000s of unrelated intervals. On a function that I pass to it. (Like a function pointer in C)

The way I imagine it, I do not need to perform any reduction, because a single thread in my thread block, will e.g. calculate h1 - h6; estimate errors and finally return me the result for the interval passed to this thread. And every thread will receive appropriate interval for the integral it needs to calculate.

Comment: The only improvement I had imagined over this was calculating the trapzoids in parallel and keeping them in shared memory and then using them for calculating errors and finally reducing them to integral result. What I can't see is how can I generate e.g. 256 thread block, and each thread again generates 8 threads which calculate the trapzoids ... if you see what I mean.

Comment: Ah, Ok. So it is the intra-thread (thus intra-interval) computation you want to prallelize further. Unfortunately a thread cannot itself spwan new threads dnyamically. And like said, *Romberg*'s hierarchical nature might be problem. But what you might do could be to make e.g. 32,000 threads (for 1000 intervals) and let each 32-pack of threads compute a single interval, using e.g *Romberg* or a simpler piecewise rule...

Comment: ...the 32-sub threads is a good number here because that's the warp size (the number of threads executing in lockstep), so you don't need any intra-interval synchronization (e.g. during the final intra-interval reduction for a piecwise rule, or in between the hierachical *Romberg* steps). But the problem is still that *Romberg* only computes a single new function value at each hierarchy step (I think) so thsi could be quite a waste of threads (especially if terminating early, before reaching step 32, so maybe a smaller sub-thread count might be a good idea (if any).

Comment: Integration is nothing else than summing values (possibly with a weight, although for equidistant grids that option is commonly overrated). So look at reduction codes.
For Romberg integration, you can run summations at multiple levels of refinement in parallel, computing the end result and error estimate from them on the CPU.

Comment: Thanks @tera and Christian for the insights. Now I know at-least how to proceed. The only question remains, are there really no CUDA libraries exiting to perform numerical integration?

Comment: @fahad: I don't think there is any general-purpose CUDA math library that does this, but you can find many examples of codes that implement numerical integration with CUDA for specific problems. See [this](http://trap9.codeplex.com/) or [that](http://eecs.oregonstate.edu/research/vlsi/teaching/ECE472_FA11/briggs_haller_cuda.pdf) for instance.

Answer (score 2):

As noticed above by Tera in his comment, from the point of view of parallel programming, integration is basically a reduction, so that a very simple way to implement integration in CUDA is exploiting the primitives of the Thrust library (see also my answer to [Simpson's method to integrate real valued functions with CUDA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16134188/simpsons-method-to-integrate-real-valued-functions-with-cuda?lq=1)).

Below is a simple example implementing the Romberg integration method by the Thrust primitives. It is a "direct" translation of the corresponding Matlab code available at this [site](http://dmpeli.math.mcmaster.ca/Matlab/Math4Q3/Lecture3-1/RombergInt.m), so this example also shows how "simply" some Matlab codes can be ported to CUDA by Thurst.

```
#include <thrust/sequence.h>

#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>

#define pi_f  3.14159265358979f                 // Greek pi in single precision

struct sin_functor
{
    __host__ __device__
    float operator()(float x) const
    {
        return sin(2.f*pi_f*x);
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    int M = 5;                          // --- Maximum number of Romberg iterations

    float a     = 0.f;                  // --- Lower integration limit
    float b     = .5f;                  // --- Upper integration limit

    float hmin  = (b-a)/pow(2.f,M-1);   // --- Minimum integration step size 

    // --- Define the matrix for Romberg approximations and initialize to 1.f 
    thrust::host_vector<float> R(M*M,1.f);

    for (int k=0; k<M; k++) {

        float h = pow(2.f,k-1)*hmin;    // --- Step size for the k-th row of the Romberg matrix

        // --- Define integration nodes
        int N = (int)((b - a)/h) + 1;
        thrust::device_vector<float> d_x(N);
        thrust::sequence(d_x.begin(), d_x.end(), a, h);

        // --- Calculate function values
        thrust::device_vector<float> d_y(N);
        thrust::transform(d_x.begin(), d_x.end(), d_y.begin(), sin_functor());

        // --- Calculate integral
        R[k*M] = (.5f*h) * (d_y[0] + 2.f*thrust::reduce(d_y.begin() + 1, d_y.begin() + N - 1, 0.0f) + d_y[N-1]);

    }

    // --- Compute the k-th column of the Romberg matrix
    for (int k=1; k<M; k++) { 

        // --- The matrix of Romberg approximations is triangular!
        for (int kk=0; kk<(M-k+1); kk++) { 

            // --- See the Romberg integration algorithm
            R[kk*M+k] = R[kk*M+k-1] + (R[kk*M+k-1] - R[(kk+1)*M+k-1])/(pow(4.f,k)-1.f); 

        } 

    }

    // --- Define the vector Rnum for numerical approximations
    thrust::host_vector<float> Rnum(M); 
    thrust::copy(R.begin(), R.begin() + M, Rnum.begin());

    for (int i=0; i<M; i++) printf("%i %f\n",i,Rnum[i]);

    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```